# Excel formula from Absolute to Relative path

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need vba to stop looking at file location from c: and just read from file name.

I'm still new to VBA and tried a few things but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("Vendor Recon")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=SUMIFS('Ta Force Report.xlsx'!Per_Diem[Brock PO'#],'Ta Force Report.xlsx'!Per_Diem[Date],A7,'Ta Force Report.xlsx'!Per_Diem[EE'#],C7)"
    End With

    With .Range("R2:R" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=COUNTIFS([BrockLenel.xlsx]Sheet1!$F:$F,C2,[BrockLenel.xlsx]Sheet1!$C:$C,A2)"
    End With
```

I want it to just look at the file name and not the c: location when give this file to my coworker.

Comment: What file name? The file that's running the code?

Comment: Put the linked files on a network share? Excel will show the full file path *because it needs the whole path to access the file*. If you actually open the linked file, Excel will show the file names without the path. If a file is on your C drive, then how is your coworker's Excel instance supposed to be able to access it?

Comment: File name is Lenel Report

Answer (score 0):

Excel will always look for the last location the file was reached within the formula. If you have always that formula set in your range without turning it into values, it will do it constantly. You can try one of the following.
a)

```
With .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
     .Formula = "Insert your formula"
     .Formula = .Value
End With
```

That will always turn into values and stop looking into a location.

b) Use a cell to store the path you want the formula to look for the values, store the cell value as a variable into VBA and use it in your formula, saying:

```
  file1 = Sheets("Variables").Range("A1")  

'You would store on that range and sheet 
    the name of the file, let's say it is "Report.xlsx"

    With .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
         .Formula = "=SUMIFS('Ta Force " & file1 & "'!Per_Diem[Brock PO'#],'Ta Force " & file1 & 
         "'!Per_Diem[Date],A7,'Ta Force " & file1 & "'!Per_Diem[EE'#],C7)"
         End With
```

You can do this substitution every time with sheet's names, paths, files, etc.

Let me know if this helps you.